# Сборщик мусора c# не очищает память

Tags: c#

Есть статичный метод

```
private static bool GetXml(string date)
{
    try
    {
        //Подключаемся к сервису
        KBODataProviderClient client = new KBODataProviderClient();
        //Получаем данные
        string[] result = client.getKBOContracts("2018-12-25", null);

        //Если данных нет
        if (result == null || result.Length <= 0)
        {
            log.InfoFormat("[{0}]|Pbo return 0 rows", runGuid);
            return false;
        }

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);

        //Сохраняем XML
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //пишем первую запись с заголовков
            sw.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
            sw.WriteLine("<CONTRACTS>");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                //удаляем заголовок
                string temp = result[i].Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>", "");
                sw.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            sw.WriteLine("</CONTRACTS>");
        }


        log.InfoFormat("[{0}]|Create XML success", runGuid);

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.ErrorFormat("[{0}]|GetXml error {1}", runGuid, ex + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        return false;
    }
}
```

При вызове метода он подключается к WCF сервису, оттуда приходит массив строк (возвращает string[]), который я потом пишу в файлик.
Проблема в том, что при получении данных разумеется съедается память, и после завершения метода память не очищается.

Собственно, я знаю то, что переменная string[] result является временной переменной и после завершения метода она должна собраться сборщиком мусора, но этого не происходит (данные занимают около 400мб в памяти)

Первым, что пришло в голову это проблема из-за статичного метода. Тогда я решил потереть ссылку

```
result = null;
GC.Collect();
```

и вызвать сборщик самому. Но и тут эффекта 0.
В чем проблема?

upd:

Использование метода идет так:

```
if (GetXml(date))
{
    //парсинг
}
```

сам метод дополнил так:

```
private static bool GetXml(string date)
{
    try
    {
        //Подключаемся к сервису
        KBODataProviderClient client = new KBODataProviderClient();
        //Получаем данные
        string[] result = client.getKBOContracts("2018-12-25", null);

        //Если данных нет
        if (result == null || result.Length <= 0)
        {
            log.InfoFormat("[{0}]|Pbo return 0 rows", runGuid);
            return false;
        }

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);

        //Сохраняем XML
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //пишем первую запись с заголовков
            sw.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
            sw.WriteLine("<CONTRACTS>");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                //удаляем заголовок
                string temp = result[i].Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>", "");
                sw.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            sw.WriteLine("</CONTRACTS>");
        }

        log.InfoFormat("[{0}]|Create XML success", runGuid);

        client.Close();
        client = null;

        result = null;

        GC.Collect();

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.ErrorFormat("[{0}]|GetXml error {1}", runGuid, ex + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Клиент сервиса я закрываю и на всякий даже null присваиваю. Далее присваиваю null строке и вызываю сборщик.

В итоге при получении данных память увеличивается до 320мб(+- офк) и после завершения падает до +-211 и продолжает работать.

Метод парсинга не занимает столько памяти, т.к без получения данных при парсинге память остается на уровне +-60мб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
попробовал Array.Clear, так-же 0 эффекта (скрин выше)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88126/discussion-on-question-by-funkyshit---c---).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Я решил проверить все дело на левых проектах потихоньку перенося код и оказалось чудом, когда на новом проекте память очищалась нормально(требовалось лишь вызвать GC.Collect())

Первым делом я решил проверить версии .net, на проекте где все работало был 4.7.1, но изменение версии не помогло. Тогда я начал в буквальном смысле добавлять по строчке и сверять код.

Причина оказалось в app.config, а именно в секции  которую генерирует VS при добавлении ссылки на сервис (там указываются таймауты и прочее).
Конкретно проблема была в том, что таймауты (CloseTimeout, OpenTimeout, ReceiveTimeout,  SendTimeout) указывались в привязке (секция basicHttpBinding).

Если я указывал эти таймауты в этой секции - память не очищалась (ни в основном, ни в каких других проектах), т.е если делал так:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="KBODataProviderPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="600000000" maxBufferSize="600000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="600000000"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

но если я указывал таймауты через код:

```
client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
```

то сборщик мусора успешно собирал мусор.

Чтобы сделать настройку времени из конфига я воспользовался ConfigurationManager

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="timeout" value="30"/>
</appSettings>
```

тогда в коде я делаю так:

```
//Получаем время, переводим его в TimeSpan (если указать их в конфиге, то память не будет очищена)
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute * int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("timeout")));
client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = time;
client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = time;
client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = time;
client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = time;
```

и сборщик мусора так-же успешно очищает память

Comment: Проблема, очевидно, не в самом факте того, что использовался конфиг, а том, что в этом конфиге были установлены достаточно большие значения для размеров буферов (maxBufferPoolSize="600000000" и т.п.)  Для сравнения, размер maxBufferPoolSize по умолчанию - 524 КБ. Внутренние буферы WCF естественно не освобождает после каждого запроса, так как это было бы бессмысленным снижением производительности. Все работает как задумано.

Comment: Буффер по прежнему установлен из конфига, но если в конфиг закинуть тайминги - то память не очищается. При этом если тайминги я не ставил, то коннект к сервису разумеется рвался и выкидывало исключение.

Но если установить тайминги через код, то память очищается, тайминги работают (нет экзепшена) и все ок. 
Сначала тоже была такая мысль, но если бы причина была в долгом коннекте, то при установке таймингов через код проблема бы осталась.

Answer (score 5):

Все языки, использующие сборщик мусора, известны своей нелюбовью возвращать память системе. Проще всего с этим смириться: как правило, неиспользуемая память быстро оседает в файле подкачки и никому там не мешает. Проблемы начинаются только когда уже и файл подкачки заканчивается.

Однако, есть несколько способов, позволяющих принудительно освободить память.

### Способ 1 - отдельный процесс.

Можно вынести вызов GetXml в отдельную программу, которая сделает всю тяжелую по памяти работу и завершится.

Это - самый медленный способ (он медленнее даже чем ничего не делать), но он позволяет быстро решить проблему с нехваткой памяти.

### Способ 2 - поточная обработка.

Этот способ требует переписывания клиента так, чтобы он не возвращал не список строк, а работал с потоками ввода-вывода. Идея в том, чтобы таскать всюду за собой Stream (или PipeReader, см. библиотеку System.Threading.Pipelines), и никогда не хранить в памяти более, к примеру, четырех килобайтов данных.

Достоинство этого способа - очень низкое потребление памяти если сделать всё правильно. Недостаток же - в том, что такие операции, как "разделить поток на две части" или "выкусить декларацию XML из начала документа", требуют сложных преобразований архитектуры.

Так, к примеру, вполне возможно что вам не удастся получить список потоков от клиента, и вместо этого придется подписываться на событие. Это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
    sw.WriteLine("<CONTRACTS>");

    var client = new KBODataProviderClient();
    client.ProcessResult += stream => 
    {
        sw.Flush();
        stream.Position += Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";
        stream.CopyTo(sw.BaseStream);
    };
    client.getKBOContracts("2018-12-25", null);

    sw.WriteLine("</CONTRACTS>");
}
```

### Способ 3 - неуправляемая память

Этот способ также требует переписывания клиента. Он может оказаться как проще поточной обработки (за счет более простых алгоритмов), так и сложнее (за счет более сложного API). Недостатком этого способа является непереносимость, так как он завязывается на конкретное API платформы.

Нужно выделить кусок неуправляемой памяти через P/Invoke (лучше всего использовать пару функций `VirtualAlloc`/`VirtualFree` - они уж точно вернут память системе), и (старых подход) либо обернуть ее в `SafeBuffer` и дальше в `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor` + `UnmanagedMemoryStream`, либо (новый подход) обернуть ее в `MemoryManager<byte>` из библиотеки System.Memory и далее работать с `Memory<byte>`

Comment: Тогда уже имеет смысл смотреть в сторону CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree и Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem/FreeCoTaskMem

Comment: Решил сделать небольшой тест, создал массив на несколько элементов, он занял память на 700мб и GC.Collect его успешно очистил.
Похоже проблема в WCF сервисе, он каким-то образом держит полученные данные

Comment: @NewView а в чём смысл этих функций при работе с крупными блоками памяти?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а отдельный домен разве не помогает так же избавиться от всего мусора?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, смысл этих функций в том что вы сможете удалять (очищать) выделенные блоки памяти независимо от кода где они инициализированны, тоесть как из управляемого кода, так и из неуправляемого. Это про способ номер 3.

Comment: @NewView а что мешает VirtualFree вызвать? :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вроде авторы из МС не рекомендуют этого делать из разных типов сборок. Для этих целей как раз созданы функции которые я привел.

Comment: @NewView во-первых, сборка-то одна, откуда возьмется вторая? Во-вторых, авторы из МС не могут "не рекомендовать" использовать WinAPI, это абсурд.

Comment: @NewView надо исходить из задачи. Если задача стоит **гарантированно** вернуть память системе - то такую гарантию даёт только VirtualFree, все остальные функции могут придержать память у себя по разным причинам.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `LocalAlloc` аналог в `c#` `Marshal.AllocHGlobal/Marshal.FreeHGlobal`, пара `CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree` имеет аналог  `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem/Marshal.CoTaskMemFree`  Пара `VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree` не имеет аналогов для очистки/выделения в `c#` и использование ее не безопасно для совместной работой с памятью из управляемого и не управляемого кода. Других вариантов совместного использования нет https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.alloccotaskmem?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @NewView вы ходите по кругу. Во-первых, вы так и не сказали в чём эта небезопасность выражается. Во-вторых, откуда вдруг взялась совместная работа из управляемого и неуправляемого кода?

Comment: И в любом случае, Маршаллер освобождает возвращаемые объекты такие как массив или строка, вызовом CoTaskMemFree ().

Comment: По кругу ходите вы, но это уже не имеет значения. От возвращаемых значений и очистки памяти - взялась совместная работа из управляемого и неуправляемого кода.

Answer (score 2):

Поведение сборщика мусора недетерминировано и как следствие он запускается тогда, когда считает нужным.

Это сделано в целях оптимизации, так как сборка мусора- это ресурсоемкая операция:

1. Надо найти объекты без ссылок
2. Затем освободить память
3. Выполнить сжатие(дефрагментацию) кучи

В вашем же случае явного вызова `GC.Collect();` память все таки должна очищаться, если вы работаете с управляемыми ресурсами и нету никаких утечек.

Память может не очищаться из-за того, что программа запущена в режиме отладки и в этом режиме переменным проливается жизнь, что логично, ведь мусор может собираться еще до выхода из метода, если видно, что переменная не видна, но во время отладки мы можем наблюдать за переменными и как следствии было бы неудобно, если бы из Watch'ей переменные пропадали во время отладки.

Попробуйте запустить в режиме релиза со всевозможными оптимизациями. Подробнее об этом написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/4244707).

Так же, вроде, Рихетр писал, что сборщик мусора может не сразу отдавать память системе, так как может предполагать, что она понадобится в ближайшее время.

Comment: Скомпилировал в Release, запускаю, ВОт до получения данных: c.radikal.ru/c05/1901/1a/24c6971b487e.png После: b.radikal.ru/b02/1901/23/512a42e2415a.png И эти 250мб он тащит за собой до конца приложения. Запускла не через VS (скомпилировал под release и запустил .exe из папки, это просто фон)

Comment: `GC.Collect();` с параметрами попробуйте.

Comment: @NewView попробовал указывать до 3 поколения, без результатов.